# Showing $\sin51^\circ =4\sin43^\circ\sin77^\circ\sin17^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Whilst using the sine rule on this question [Is there an elementary method of finding this missing angle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946494/is-there-an-elementary-method-of-finding-this-missing-angle)  the following connection became apparent
$$\sin51^\circ =4\sin43^\circ\sin77^\circ\sin17^\circ$$

It seems surprising given that some of the values are prime numbers.

If we didn't know about the background situation, is there a way to show this and is this kind of thing part of a well known set of connections between trigonometric values?

Comment: Notice $51^\circ = 3\cdot 17^\circ$, $43^\circ = 60^\circ - 17^\circ$, and $77^\circ = 60^\circ + 17^\circ$.

Comment: @aschepler  thankyou for pointing this out, it answers why the one in the question is true, I was unaware of the identity